# What is this casting achieving in C Code

Tags: c, casting

I am relatively new to C Code and am trying to interpret the outcome of these lines of C that are doing some casting.

ASS_CODE is a a character string of up to 4 characters that may or may not be numeric, ASCII_ZERO is a constant defined as 48 and ASCII_ONE is a constant defined as 49. I'm guessing that either this is trying to force some sort of true or false outcome based on whether ASS_CODE is numeric or otherwise or alternatively testing if the string is '0'or '1', but am not entirely sure

```
 if ((int)(*ASS_CODE) == ASCII_ZERO)
       {
         calc_SDIS_EL13();
        }
         else if ((int)(*ASS_CODE) == ASCII_ONE)
        {
         do_gn11();
       } else
            {
               ........
            }
       }
```

Comment: A bit more context would help. Casting does not do string-to-integer conversion.

Comment: Without more context it's hard to say anything for certain, but it seems to me that the casting isn't really needed.

Comment: From what you tell us, this code does exactly the same as `if (ASS_CODE[0] == ASCII_ZERO)` why anyone added those casts is anyones guess.

Comment: When you say "ASS_CODE is a a character string ...", that lacks specificity as to the _type_ of `ASS_CODE`.  Please post the definition of `ASS_CODE` for quality answers.

Comment: The definition of ASS_CODE is    char   ASS_CODE[5];

Answer (score 3):

If `char` as in `*ASS_CODE`, is a signed `char` or an unsigned `char` narrower than `int` (1 of these 2 is almost always the case) will be promoted to `int`.  The *integer constant* `48` is of type `int` and so the cast `(int)` is unnecessary.

On rare platforms, `char` as in `*ASS_CODE`, is an unsigned `char` as wide as `int/unsigned`.  `*ASS_CODE` is promoted to `unsigned` as part of the pending compare operation.  Comparing an `unsigned` to the *integer constant* `48` (which is an `int`) may warn about comparing `int` to `unsigned`.   The cast in this case will quiet the warning.

Answer (score 0):

```
char ASS_CODE[4] = { ... };
#define ASCII_ZERO 48

if ((int)(*ASS_CODE) == ASCII_ZERO)
```

Apparently, this is code for a non-ASCII execution character set, or some developer who is very careful. Otherwise the `ASCII_ZERO` constant would not be necessary.

My first thought was that the type `char` was equal to `unsigned char` on that platform, and that the cast would be needed to suppress a compiler warning. But no matter how I define the constant, GCC doesn't omit any warning. I tried this:

```
enum { ASCII_ZERO = 48 };

void x() {
    char ASS_CODE[4] = {0};
    if (ASS_CODE[0] == ASCII_ZERO) {} else {}
}
```

The next idea is that the code must conform to some industry standard, like MISRA. This standard might require that the left-hand side and the right-hand side of every binary operator must have the same type. And since 48 has type `int`, the character must be cast to exactly that type.

Comment: For your first part, this is because  in `a == b` , where `a` is an unsigned char and `b` is an int, `a` gets promoted to an int (as long as an int type is wider than an unsigned char - which it is on your platform.)

Answer (score 0):

> I am [...] trying to interpret the outcome of these lines of C that are doing some casting.
>
> [...]
>   ASS_CODE is a a character string of up to 4 characters that may or may not be numeric, ASCII_ZERO is a constant defined as 48
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> if ((int)(*ASS_CODE) == ASCII_ZERO)
> ```

If `ASS_CODE` has type `char *` or type `char[n]` for some `n`, then `*ASSCODE` has type `char`, and evaluates to the same thing as `ASS_CODE[0]` -- *i.e.*, the first character of the string.  The literal `48` to which macro `ASCII_ZERO` expands represents a value of type `int`; specifically, it is the value of the `'0'` character in ASCII-compatible character encodings.

Cast operators have higher precedence than the `==` operator, so in evaluating the condition, the value of `*ASS_CODE` (a `char`) is first converted to type `int` and then compared to the right-hand operand (already an `int`).  The condition evaluates to `1` (true) when the first character of `ASS_CODE` is the digit `'0'` (assuming an ASCII-compatible encoding).  It is conceivable that `ASCII_ZERO` is used instead of a character literal (`'0'`) because a comparison specifically to the *ASCII* sense of 0 is desired even when a different character encoding is in use.  In any event, that is the effect that will be produced.

I speculate that the reason for the cast was to make both operands have the same type, or maybe just to emphasize that the comparison was being performed on `int` values.  It has no effect whatever on the semantics of the program, however, because the operands of the `==` operator are subject to "the usual arithmetic conversions" before the operation is evaluated anyway, and in this case, that would involve converting the left-hand operand to `int` even without the explicit cast.